# Is there a way to switch from a rootless user to a root user in a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, rhel7

I created a RHEL 7 Docker container using the Dockerfile USER instruction to create a rootless user.
I can exec into the container, issue the whoami command and I can identify myself as that non-root user.
However, I cannot execute any root-equivalent command i.e. yum update because it prompts me for the root password. When I sudo or su - it prompts me for the root password even though I never assigned a password to root.

1. Why is the system prompting me for a root password if I never created one? So I can elevate my rights and execute priviledge commands?
2. Can you switch from a rootless user to root in a container that was created with a rootless user?

Comment: (If you're trying to use tools like `yum` to install software, you should probably do that in the Dockerfile, not the running container: any changes you make with `docker exec` will be lost as soon as the container exits.)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the system prompting me for a root password if I never created one? So I can elevate my rights and execute privileged commands?

Because by default the `root` account is locked (so it looks like it has a password, but it's not a valid one).

> Can you switch from a rootless user to root in a container that was created with a rootless user?

If you've installed and configure `sudo` you could become `root` in the container using `sudo`. However, rather than "switching" to the `root` account, it's probably easier to create a `root` shell using the `-u` argument to `docker exec`:

```
docker exec -u root -it mycontainer -- bash
```

Comment: Or if you want to run yum install in build time you can extend the Dockerfile and use the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) command to set root user.

USER root
do your root stuff
USER non-root user
do non-root user stuff

Am not 100% sure with RHEL if it is blocked there as well, but if it is not it is also an option instead of executing into the container. Which will give you repeatability and documentation on what is going on with the image before the container is actually created.